# how to use js function from loaded ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

the function is in the page loading the ajax but i'm trying to call the function

codes:

[ajax]

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "loginpersonal.asp",
data: "id=<%=request("id")%>",
beforeSend: function() {
    $("#personaltab").hide();
},
success: function(msg){
    $("#personaltab").empty().append(msg);
},
complete: function() {
    $("#personaltab").slideDown();
},
error: function() {
    $("#personaltab").append("error").slideDown();
}
});
```

[the js function]

```
function GetCount(t){
    if(t>0) {
        total = t
    }
    else {
        total -=1;
    }
    amount=total;
                                            if(amount < 0){
        startpersonalbid();
    }
    else{
        days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";
        days=Math.floor(amount/86400);//days
        amount=amount%86400;
        hours=Math.floor(amount/3600);//hours
        amount=amount%3600;
        mins=Math.floor(amount/60);//minutes
        amount=amount%60;

        secs=Math.floor(amount);//seconds
        if(days != 0){out += days +":";}
        if(days != 0 || hours != 0){out += hours +":";}
        if(days != 0 || hours != 0 || mins != 0){out += ((mins>=10)?mins:"0"+mins) +":";}
        out += ((secs>=10)?secs:"0"+secs) ;
        document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;
        setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
    }
}
window.onload=function(){
GetCount(<%= DateDiff("s", Now,privatesellstartdate&" "&privatesellstarttime ) %>);
```

so at the end of the loginpersonal.asp from the ajax... if it does what it suppose to do... i'm trying to call the function GetCount() again.

Comment: How are you loading the script?  Are you `eval`'ing or injecting a `<script>`?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call to javascript included on ajax pages for security. you need to call the external javascript and eval it into the application. using a framework, many frameworks do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library you are using, but I use HTML like the following:

```
<div>
  My markup
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function ($) {
   window.myFunction = function() {
      alert("Running from ajax loaded file");
   }
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

And then with jquery, I call it like this:

```
$("div#loadMe").load("/snippets/file.html", function(response, status, xhr){
  if (status == "error") {
    alert ("Error");
    return;
  }
  // do stuff
  window.myFunction();
});
```

Of course, you could use whatever library you like to do the ajax loading.  I haven't tested the code above, but it is similar to code I have in production now.

I believe that with jquery, you have to load the ENTIRE file, or the scripts won't run.  If you target just a certain element within a file, the scripts don't get loaded or run. In other words, you can't do this: `load("/snippets/file.html #container")` and have your scripts run.

Also, I think you must be on the same site for this to work, unless you are loading using jsonp.